# How to disable mouse wheel zoom on Google streetview?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Consider the following example code:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple.html

I can do `scrollwheel: false` on a mapOptions to disable mouse wheel zoom. The feature is not implemented on the streetview panoramaOptions.

In Chrome, I can safely disable mouse wheel zoom on the streetview simply by.

```
$('#pano *').bind('mousewheel', function(){
    return false;
});
```

However this does not work in elsewhere. Please help me get it working in top 3-5 browsers?

Comment: This issue has now been fixed, just use scrollwheel: false within your StreetViewPanorama options.

Comment: Yes, it is true that you can set scrollwheel to false to fix this issue, however, when mouse is over the street view, you can no longer scroll with 2 fingers on mac osx mouse pad.  Which makes me believe that you would also not be able to scroll on mobile devices if you start drag from within the street view map element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a confirmed feature request with Gmaps API issues http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2557. Let's hope Google's engineers will look into it when they get trough more important bugs. I hate to hold my breath, but I'll park this for now.

Comment: This issue has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to Subgurim.net, this is how to do it;

```
  [powerscript -  other event]
CONSTANT integer WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 522
IF message.number = WM_MOUSEWHEEL AND & KeyDown (KeyControl!) THEN
   message.processed = TRUE
   RETURN 1
END IF
```

I realise that you are using Javascript, and this is a VB example, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code to avoid double click zoom - pretty sure it could be adapted to scroll wheel zoom. zoom: 1 being my preferred zoom stage here, but could be anything.

```
$("#panorama").dblclick( function(){

   panorama.setPov(  {
      heading: panorama.getPov().heading,
      pitch: panorama.getPov().pitch, zoom: 1 
   });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, check my reply on http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2557

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy workaround: by adding a  layer before the streetview  with a higher z-index, you will prevent the zooming function of the Streetview.

```
<div id="panorama" style="position: absolute;left:0; top: 0;height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: -1;opacity: 1"></div>
<div id="layerBeforePanorama" style="position: absolute;left:0; top: 0;height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 0;opacity: 1"></div>

<script>
var panoOptions = {
    position: latlng,
    pov: {
        heading: 0,
        pitch: 0
    }
  };
var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('panorama'), panoOptions);
</script>
```